# Is speed 1.2 mb/sec normal on WebUsb?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, usb, webusb

I am making a communication web app that connects the usb device using **stm32** mcu to the **Chrome browser**.

When I run the code I wrote, I'm fetching data at a rate of about **1.2 mbytes / sec.**

This is based on the execution speed of the pure **"transferIn"** function except for encoding and data interpretation.  In my case, transferIn uses a bulk endpoint.

I know that **1.2 mbytes / sec** is only about the speed of **usb 1.1.**

Is this normal?

I am wondering if there is a more advanced method, but I do not know.

Comment: STM32 device does not say anything. There are many STM32 devices. Some are only FS capable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase throughput by having multiple `transferIn()` requests queued. This makes sure that the host is always ready to received more data from the device rather than waiting for your application to process the data before asking for more.

Comment: Many STM devices are only FS so 1.2MB is 100% OK.

Comment: thnx~ Reilly Grant, thnx~ P__J___

Comment: @Reilly Grant
You mentioned "multiple trasferIn () request queued", but it is not clear how this should be implemented specifically.

I used the Web Worker to call several postMessages containing the trasferIn () command, but this also did not exceed 1.2mb / s.

Comment: Are you sure that your device is operating in high-speed mode? Even if it is a USB 2.0 device it can still be limited by the hardware capabilities to low-speed mode.